# Override org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping in child pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

Is there a way to override configurations of the m2e lifecycle-mapping plugin in a child pom.xml? I have a parent pom.xml that I can't change. It contains the following xml:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>some.group.id</groupId>
                                <artifactId>some-artifact-id</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.x.x,</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>someGoal</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore/>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I want to override this behaviour in my project. I tried to put the same configuration in my `pom.xml` and replace `<ignore/>` with `<execute/>`, but that just results in a merged configuration containing `<ignore/>` and `<execute/>`.
Is there an other way I can try to get rid of this m2e lifecycle mapping?

Comment: Where did you place the (almost) same configuration in your pom. Can you add that segment to the post please.

Comment: Its on the same position as the configuration from the parent pom. That is `project/build/pluginManagement/plugins/plugin`. When I use Eclipse to open the "Effective POM" tab, I see the action node `<action><execute /><ignore /></action>`

Comment: Try putting it in `project/build/plugins/plugin` instead. This should override the plugin definition that is done in the pluginManagement section of the parent.

Comment: I can put that configuration there, but that wont work. The lifecycle-mapping plugin is not a real plugin. It is just a way to tell the Eclipse M2e plugin how to handle other maven plugins in the Eclipse build. If there is no connector, the usual way is to use the lifecycle-mapping plugin to tell m2e not to execute this plugin. Nevertheless in a normal maven build, the plugin is executed.